# Downloading pdf file from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, download

This is the Code i've used... file will be downloaded successfully, but it will not open. and shows an error as "adobe reader could not open file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"..

Comment: Code is not included. Try downloading the file with wget, and check if the size is zero or not

Comment: Can't see your code still: I'll undownvote if you edit it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just store the location where the PDF stored on site root or somewhere and download from there because IMO giving PDFs to MySQL is not a very good idea.

Update:

Here is a very simple code I used mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array for the example but you should use your own method of working with your database.

```
    <?php 
    /*
    First you need a basic database with this info. 
    Example database: 
    Table name: pdfs
    id | name | location 
    ---------------------
    1  | test | /site/pdf/mypdf.pdf

     */

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pdfs WHERE name = 'test'";

    //Use your favorite mysql function for example I will use mysql_query() but this is deprecated. 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //This is also deprecated do not use this
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<a href='http://site.com/".$array['location']."'>Download</a>";
    ?>
```

Comment: ya.. idea is good.. can u place the code to store the location in php

Comment: I have updated the post. You can change the script in different ways for example you could add another column with extension and not include it in the name. For any help comment :P